# How to create JPA application in eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

How to create a JPA application using Google's datastore in Eclipse? What are the steps to create a Google App Engine application in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

First, install the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html#Download_the_Google_Plugin_for_Eclipse). Second, check [Getting Started: Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/) and especially [**Creating a Project**](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating.html). Follow the documented steps. Third, jump to [Using JPA with App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html).

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html
ya i already refer that link in that they gave steps to create JPA application.But in eclipse on option is there (i.e) file-->new-->JPA Project.like that i created one jpa project .But in that no war files .

Comment: @megala I don't mean to be rude but I provided you all the pointers. I told you to check the "Getting Started: Java" guide, there is a "Create a Project" section (I added a link to it but everything you need was already there). If you are beginning with GAE, you should do things by the book. If you don't, expect some troubles.

Comment: you should require a remote desktop access and set it up :) (+1)